# OSX Mavericks - Recovering from an Invalid Record Count error

Tags: macos, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, osx-mavericks

I've ended up with a friend's Macbook Pro that won't boot. They've given it to me asking me to fix as they have family photos not backed up (naughty, I know!) they want retrieved.

When booting up, only the recovery partition is visible when pressing Option at start up. After booting off a USB Rescue disk, in Disk Utility, the disk is visible, but greyed out.

[image]

When I use the Disk Utility to repair the disk, it says it's not repairable due to an invalid record count.

[image: Invalid record count]

I found [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4313082) that suggested running the following command from a terminal session (still in the USB Rescue Disk boot):

```
/sbin/fsck_hfs -yprd /dev/disk0s2
```

Which produces the following output:

```
-bash-3.2# /sbin/fsck_hfs -yprd /dev/disk0s2
/dev/rdisk0s2: starting
journal_replay(/dev/disk0s2) returned 22
        Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=16384 cacheSize=524288K
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-226.1.1).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid forward link (0x88B3FF4E)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid backward link (0xD4023F69)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node kind (-16)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid node height (96)
hfs_swap_BTNode: invalid record count (0xFBFE)
   Invalid record count
(3, 3)
** The volume   could not be verified completely.
        volume check failed with error 2
        volume type is pure HFS+
        primary MDB is at block 0 0x00
        alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00
        primary VHB is at block 2 0x02
        alternate VHB is at block 975093950 0x3a1ec0be
        sector size = 512 0x200
        VolumeObject flags = 0x07
        total sectors for volume 975093952 0x3a1ec0c0
        total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
        CheckHFS returned -1317, fsmodified = 0
-bash-3.2#
```

I did try it from Single user mode and it displayed random ascii characters saying `journal not found, waiting 10 seconds` several times before displaying the same information above.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to repair the OSX partition and, or at the very least, save the data/photos?

Comment: Looks like the kind of task for [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) - but I hope you have a backup anyway.

Comment: I'd try to boot from a linux live cd and from there try to mount the disk.  Copy over as much data as you can.  From those errors, I don't think you're going to have much luck repairing the disk; at best you'll have to wipe it and reinstall osx.  at worst, the disk is physically damaged and you'll need to buy a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same situation today. My MacBook Pro disk died and was showing the "invalid record count" error. I wasn't able to boot, to mount the disk and copy any data out of it.

As much as I didn't enjoy shelling 100$+ on the commercial software the [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/details3.html) fixed my problem and I recovered my data. Highly recommended!

The steps:

- When you install the DiskWarrior it asks you where do you want it to be installed, choose USB as a target
- Press "Alt" during booting, choose recover option
- Go to terminal, run the DiskWarrior from /Volumes/yourusbpath
- It will open the new window, which will allow to repair the disk

Comment: Yep, this is what I had to do. It wasn't able to restore the macbook to working order, I had to reformat but I was able to resurrect the data I needed from it.